Real Analysis Question about Limit points and ε-neighborhoods
The question says "Prove that a point $x$ is a limit point of a set $A$ iff every ε-neighborhood of $x$ intersects $A$ at some point other than $x$."
I am having trouble proving the reverse direction, that is, if every ε-neighborhood of $x$ intersects $A$ at some point other than $x$, then $x$ is a limit point of $A$. My attempt is by contrapositive, so I want to prove that if $x$ is not a limit point then there is an ε-neighborhood of $x$ that does not intersect $A$. When I try to do this, though, I end up with the fact that for all sequences of numbers in $A$, there exists an $N$ st for all $n>N$ $a_n$ is outside the ε-neighborhood of $x$ but I don't see where to go from here. How can I proceed from here? Thanks!

What is a limit point of a set to you?

Yes, what is your definition of a limit point?

With the usual topological definition and $A$ taken in the metric topology, the statement is trivial.

My textbook says $x$ is a limit point of a set $A$ if there is a sequence of points $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$, ... from $A$ \ ${x}$ such that $a_n$ approaches $x$

Sorry I was unaware that that isn't the usual definition but after looking it up I see it's alternatively defined in the way the question asks.

Your negation of "$x$ is a limit point of $A$" (in your attempt of proof by contradiction) is very wrong. Replace "there exists an $N$ st for all $n>N$" by "there exists an $\epsilon>0$ s.t. for all $N$, there exists an $n>N$"

It is better to simply construct a sequence converging to $x$.
For each $n = 1, 2, \dotsc$, take a point $a_n \in B_{1/n}(x) \cap (A \setminus \{x\})$. Then you have constructed a sequence $a_n \in A \setminus \{x\}$ that converges to $x$. (you actually have to prove it converges to $x$)

To prove the statement

If every $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $x$ intersects $A$ at some point other than $x$, then $x$ is a limit point of $A$.

where your definition has

$x$ is a limit point of $A$ if there is a sequence of points $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^+}$ from $A - \{ x \}$ converging to $x$.

we just need to construct such a sequence. So assume the hypothesis. For each $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, take $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{n} > 0$; by hypothesis, the set $U_n = (A - \{ x \}) \cap B_d \left(x, \frac{1}{n} \right)$ is nonempty. For each $n$, let $a_n$ be an arbitrary element of $U_n$ (countable choice assumed). We claim that the sequence $(a_n)$ defined in this way converges to $x$, finishing the proof.
To show that, let $\delta > 0$ be arbitrary. If $\delta \ge 1$, then you can check that all elements of the sequence have $d (x, a_n) < \delta$. Otherwise, consider $N = \lceil \frac{1}{\delta} \rceil \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. For each $n > N$, we have that $\frac{1}{n} < \delta$. Then $a_n \in B_d (x, \delta)$ implies that $d (x, a_n) < \delta$.
